# What is the actual relationship between Brahma and saraswati?

Tags: brahma, saraswati

I seriously want to know, how are Brahma and saraswati related, is she brahma's consort, daughter, wife?

I know that all of the child of Brahma are mind born and he doesn't have any genertic/human kind of kids his children are either spiritual gods or material humans, he doesn't have any sexual relationship with anyone.

I know consort and wife are two different things, consort is a partner, while wife is married partner so is saraswati shown along with brahma because she is consort of Brahma or his wife?