# Which Vedic verses describe Saraswati as wife of Brahma?

Tags: vedas, brahma, saraswati, hymn

Does any Vedic sukta call Saraswati as the wife of Brahma-prajapati?

Note: This is not a dup. of "[Which puranas/upapuranas mention about marriage between Brahma and Saraswati?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24901)" which is about references from Puranas.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto that question is mine too, I'm just confused with this whole saraswati brahma saga, somewhere she is daughter, wife or merely a consort. Now I'm looking for Vedic evidences.

Comment: Can you add the sources where is she daughter and where is she wife ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto here read keshav's answer- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7075/what-is-the-relation-of-saraswati-vak-with-the-river-saraswati-and-trinity-or

Comment: Learn the concept of Non-dualism and you'll never be confused.

Comment: @AnubhavJha The Vedas are also covered in that question when you use "Which scriptures" and you have also not accepted those answers. Now, there are two ways. 1) Choosing this as a duplicate or 2) limiting that question only to Puranas and Upa Puranas. Option 1 seems good to me.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma seems user has chosen option 2..hence voting to reopen..

Comment: No, in the Vedas Sarasvati was not described as Brahma's wife. Read this answer. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45864/who-is-goddess-sarasvatī-how-the-goddess-of-river-transformed-into-the-goddess